# What is "document tree content"?

Tags: html

I answered a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621127/list-of-html-elements-that-support-the-css-before-and-after-pseudo-selectors/8621345) about CSS psuedo elements with a reference to the [document tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#doctree), or more specifically, **document tree content**.

> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content
>   ...the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements specify the location of content before and after an element's document tree content.

The W3C's explanation is very brief:

> **Document tree**
>   The tree of elements encoded in the source document. Each element in this tree has exactly one parent, with the exception of the root element, which has none.

Although I've been searching for a more explicit reference as to what exactly this means, I can't find anything useful. Can someone help explain exactly what **document tree content** is, and how to tell whether or not an HTML element has it?

Comment: Perhaps the content of the specific case being looked at?  Or, perhaps the values of the elements, as this is what 'content' typically refers to (i.e., "code" vs "content")?  It seems like the latter, reading what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is referring to the hierarchal nature of HTML (elements having parents, siblings, children, ancestors, descendants, etc), and the content the child elements of the element of reference.

Comment: Well that was basically my guess as well, but it's still not quite clear to me. So for example, does `<option>` have "document tree content"?

Comment: @Madmartigan - [`<option>`'s content model](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-option-element.html#the-option-element) is `Text`. If the `<option>` element is in the document tree, then it's child TextNodes are also nodes in the document tree, so yes, `<option>` has document tree content.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what they mean by "document tree content" is the structure or the contents of the document tree rooted at given element, essentially the element's descendants.

Comment: Well that was basically my guess as well but it's still not quite clear to me. So for example, does `<head>` have "document tree content"?

Comment: I suppose any element with children (themselves elements) has document tree content.

Answer (score 0):

Attached is a full quote from the OP's source.

You can see that the source is referring to generated non-code portions of the document.  This is because a document is often separated into "code" and "content" by developers.

> Authors specify the style and location of generated content with the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements. As their names indicate, the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content
>   before and after an element's document tree content. The 'content'
>   property, in conjunction with these pseudo-elements, specifies what is
>   inserted.
>
> For example, the following rule inserts the string "Note: " before the
>   content of every P element whose "class" attribute has the value
>   "note":
>
> p.note:before { content: "Note: " }