# select element(optgroup) value is not displaying in safari - CSS

Tags: html, css, safari

Css Content Property does not work for `Select` element on Safari. But it perfectly works for other browsers.

[Check my fiddle across all browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/8zm3vona/2/)

---

**Refer these Images between `Chrome` and `Safari` browsers.**
[image]
[image]

---

Note: It perfectly works for other elements except Select tag.

Comment: can you share the images between browsers to see the differences ?

Comment: While the link to a live demo is appreciated it does not replace the rule that questions must be self-contained, please: add your "*[mcve]*" code to the question itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I voted to close because of the lack of code in the question (as identified in my previous comment); however this question is also a duplicate of "[Pseudo elements and `select` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21103542/82548)," if anyone would care to close the question (unless the OP edits in an explanation of how this question is sufficiently different to merit remaining open to new answers).

Comment: @Manjuboyz I have attached the image

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue when you use `optgroup` for both `firefox` and `safari` unfortunately, there are very less options we can try for `select` so here is one of the alternative option you can use, in-case if this is not an issue.

> This will remain same for all browsers.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

select {
  height: 200px
}

span:before {
  content: attr(label);
}

.Header {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="cars" multiple>
  <!-- you can use this as header -->
  <option class="Header" disabled>Swedish Cars</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <!-- you can use this as header -->
  <option class="Header" disabled>German Cars</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<span label='I am span content'></span>
```