# Woocommerce checkout form how to add a note under the State field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I'm trying to add a note directly under the state field on the checkout form:

[image]

With something like this:

> **"If you need medication mailed outside of NC or SC, or you are not a client, please call".**

I've tried various methods to accomplish this, but none seem to work. I've tried using CSS:

```
 #billing_state:after {
    content: "If you need medication mailed outside of NC or SC, or you are not a client, please call";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
  }
```

I've also tried adding this to the functions.php file:

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_text', function ($field, $key, $args, $value) {
     if ($key === 'billing_state') {
         $field .= 'If you need medication mailed outside of NC or SC, or you are not a client, please 
         call';
     }

     return $field;
 }, 10, 4);
```

But neither of these methods are working. This is the code for the state field I'm trying to target:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your css rules didn't work because it's a `select` tag and you can't use css `pseudo elements` on `select` tags!!! If you want more info on this topic, you could read about it on the following pages:

> [Pseudo elements and SELECT tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103542/pseudo-elements-and-select-tag)

and

> [problem with <select> and :after with CSS in WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532649/problem-with-select-and-after-with-css-in-webkit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now in order to get css rules to work the way you want it, you need to target a different html element with your css!

```
.woocommerce p#billing_state_field::after{
  content: "If you need medication mailed outside of NC or SC, or you are not a client, please call" !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

This should work but if it didn't, then I would use the following method as an `alternative way`:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_notice', 20);

function custom_checkout_notice($fields){
  $fields['billing']['custom_notice'] = array(
    'label' => 'If you need medication mailed outside of NC or SC, or you are not a client, please call',
    'priority' => 65 # you could change this number to move the notice up and down the list!
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

The snippet above, will generate a new text field. A way to make it work the way you want, you could do the following instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_notice', 20);

function custom_checkout_notice($fields){
  $fields['billing']['custom_notice'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => '',
    'placeholder' => 'If you need medication mailed outside of NC or SC, or you are not a client, please call',
    'priority' => 65 # you could change this number to move the notice up and down the list!
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

and then add this to your style sheet of your active theme or active child theme!

```
input#custom_notice{
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```